# How do I assign a value basis the order it comes in a column for each group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data, values at End1, End2 appears in an order, I want to have another column that determines the order at which it appear at End1. There is a possibility that value at End2 may never reach at End1, but if it appears anywhere, it will have an impact on the order next item.

```
ID   End1   End2  
1    A      B      
1    A      B      
1    B      A     
1    A      B
1    C      B
1    C      D
1    D      C
1    C      D
1    D      C
2    A      B
2    A      B
2    A      C
2    A      C
2    C      A
2    C      A
2    D      C
2    C      D
2    D      C
```

I want to have the following output:

```
ID   End1   End2  Order
1    A      B      1
1    A      B      1
1    B      A      2     
1    A      B      1
1    C      B      3 
1    C      D      3
1    D      C      4
1    C      D      3
1    D      C      4
2    A      B      1
2    A      B      1
2    A      C      1
2    A      C      1 
2    C      A      3
2    C      A      3
2    D      C      4
2    C      D      3
2    D      C      4
```

I tried different functions, but they are all counting the occurrences of the value. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**: There are two other requirements here:

1. The Order resets for each group. While A may have order 1 in ID=1, but it may have order 2 for any other ID.
2. Some of the suggested solutions are not taking into account that a item at End2 (As for B in ID=2), may never reach at End1. But it will impact the order of items coming after it.

To make it more clear ID=3 within the same data set may have the following data:

```
ID End1 End2
2  D    C  
.....  
3  B    E 
3  E    B
3  E    B
3  G    B
3  C    B
```

And the output required would be

```
ID End1 End2 Order
2  D    C    4 
.....  
3  B    E    1
3  E    B    2
3  E    B    2 
3  G    B    3
3  C    B    4
```

Comment: I am just trying put in each row the order number in which the values in column End1 appeared. So if A appeared first for ID = 1 the order will be 1 for A in End1 and for all IDs = 1.  I hope I am making sense here.

Comment: Your desired result does not match the updated requirements.

Comment: @wwii - It does. There is a possibility that all the values can appear in same order at some other ID. Or there can be different values altogether for another ID. Hence I updated my other requirements.

Comment: So the *Order* for ID==2 is `ABABACACCACA...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set index as `ID` and use [`DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to reshape the frame, then use [`Series.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.factorize.html) to create a numeric array identifying distinct value thereby creating a series `s`, then use [`Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) on `s` and agg using `first`(as we have to first give priority to the order for column `End1` over `End2`):

```
s = pd.Series(df.set_index('ID').stack().factorize()[0] + 1)
df['Order'] = s.groupby(s.index // 2).first()
```

**EDIT**: If we need to consider **distinct** values per group:

```
s = pd.Series(np.hstack([g.factorize()[0] + 1 for _, g in
                         df.set_index('ID').stack().groupby(level=0)]))
df['Order'] = s.groupby(s.index // 2).first()
```

Result:

```
    ID End1 End2  Order
0    1    A    B      1
1    1    A    B      1
2    1    B    A      2
3    1    A    B      1
4    1    C    B      3
5    1    C    D      3
6    1    D    C      4
7    1    C    D      3
8    1    D    C      4
9    2    A    B      1
10   2    A    B      1
11   2    A    C      1
12   2    A    C      1
13   2    C    A      3
14   2    C    A      3
15   2    D    C      4
16   2    C    D      3
17   2    D    C      4
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach could be to concatenate the string values in End1+End2, and use the result as key of dictionary. The algorithm would look something like:

```
counter = 1
new_column = []
my_dict = dict()
for row in data:
  key_to_check = row[End1]+row[End2]
  if key_to_check in my_dict:
     new_column.append(my_dict[key_to_check])
  else:
     my_dict[key_to_check] = counter
     new_column.append(my_dict[key_to_check])
  counter += 1

## append new_column to the data
```

Comment: Why I need to concatenate End1+End2? The order is not dependent on the value of End1 & End 2 together. Hence, making a key doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 2, 10: 2, 11: 2, 12: 2, 13: 2, 14: 2, 15: 2, 16: 2, 17: 2},
                   'End1': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'A', 4: 'C', 5: 'C', 6: 'D', 7: 'C', 8: 'D', 9: 'A', 10: 'A', 11: 'A', 12: 'A', 13: 'C', 14: 'C', 15: 'D', 16: 'C', 17: 'D'},
                   'End2': {0: 'B', 1: 'B', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'B', 5: 'D', 6: 'C', 7: 'D', 8: 'C', 9: 'B', 10: 'B', 11: 'C', 12: 'C', 13: 'A', 14: 'A', 15: 'C', 16: 'D', 17: 'C'}})
```

[pandas.unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) will give order of appearance.

Find the index in `sequence` of each value of the `End1` column. Group by `'ID'` so the *order* is unique to `'ID'`. Stacking each group/DataFrame serves to *flatten* the `['End1','End2']` columns.

```
df = df.set_index('ID')
gb = df.groupby('ID')
for k,g in gb:
    sequence = pd.unique(g.stack())
    order = (g.End1.to_numpy() == sequence[:,None]).argmax(0) + 1        
    df.loc[k,'Order'] = order
df.Order = df.Order.astype(int)
```

---

```
def f(g):
    sequence = pd.unique(g.stack())
    order = (g.End1.to_numpy() == sequence[:,None]).argmax(0) + 1
    return order
gb = df.groupby('ID')
orders = gb.apply(f)
df.loc[orders.index,'foo'] = np.concatenate(orders.values)
```

Comment: Thanks. But It won't reset the order for each group, it will just look into the sequence of the End1 and use for another group.

Comment: @PulkitJain - your example does not look like it *resets* for `'ID'==2` ... Your desired output shows `2 C A`  with a value of `3` for the order.

Comment: @PulkitJain - I believe it is fixed.

Comment: Yes Shubham-sharma 's answer did the trick.